# How to click a button in an opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I am trying to create some sort of workflow in GreaseMonkey.
I start with GreaseMonkey defining jQuery if it isn't already defined:

```
/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
(function(a,b).......function(){return f})})(window); // packed version
jQuery.noConflict();
/*! end of jQuery */
```

Then, it periodically checks a web page (jQuery.ajax/type=get/url:window.location.href).
When some condition is met, a window is created using

```
var url = <some page on the same domain>
var opened = window.open(url, "XYZ");
```

The question is how to get a button on the opened window to click.  Let's say on the page there is a button

```
<input type="button" id="clickme"
```

I've tried the obvious such as

```
opened.document.getElementById('clickme').click()
jQuery(opened.document).find('#clickme').click()
```

But neither work.  This is probably a GreaseMonkey issue so would like to see if anyone has something similar working.  My current workaround is to set up another GreaseMonkey script against the opened url which clicks the button if window.name = 'XYZ'.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi whatever, that doesn't change the fact that this is a vague question

Comment: It's vague, because (1) several different things can be considered "windows" and **how** you open it matters a great deal. (2) Likewise, several things can be considered "buttons" and different types require different techniques. (3) Whether it is same-domain makes a huge difference but is not indicated.  (4) Greasemonkey problems are almost always very page-specific.  Details (not given) matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty vague; I'm assuming you're creating a window using `window.open` or something to that effect, and want to interact with the DOM inside.

You should be able to use the reference to the newly-opened window as you would use the `window` variable in regular JavaScript:

```
window.document.getElementById(...).doStuff(...)
```

becomes

```
var thatWindowReference = window.open(...);
...
thatWindowReference.document.getElementById(...).doStuff(...)
```

If you've got jQuery loaded inside the window, then you can do

```
thatWindowReference.$('selector').doStuff(...)
```

As for how to simulate a click on a button inside that window:

```
thatWindowReference.document.getElementById('thatButton').click();
```

or using jQuery:

```
thatWindowReference.$('#thatButton').click();
```

**Edit**: Without using jQuery from inside the new window ([test it out on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keY7x/1/)):

```
var w = window.open('about:blank');
w.document.write('<button id="test" onclick="alert(\'I was clicked\');">Hello</button>');
$(w.document.body).find('#test').click();
```

Comment: But can I use jQuery (loaded on this page) goodness on that page?

Comment: Unfortunately, the domain doesn't use jQuery. In GreaseMonkey I even have to load jQuery, so it definitely doesn't isn't loaded in the new window.  Why doesn't jQuery(other.document).find(...) work?

Comment: Try `jQuery(otherWindow.document.body).find('selector')`

Comment: I added a jsFiddle example with that code and it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/keY7x/1/

Comment: +1, your answer is fine for windows opened using `window.open` and on the same domain.  It's not clear that this is the OP's situation though.